# hosting JQuery UI issue (why won't my slider work)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is a very pedantic question.  I've hit my head against the wall for an hour with this stupid little issue and I can't figure it out.

I've decided to host Jquery UI so that I can use the prebuilt css themes.  I assume that the version hosted by google doesn't come with a pre-built theme.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So anyway, I'm importing the css sheet and scripts correctly, but my slider just won't show up. I added a div to the markup with the class name testSubject.

```
$(function(){
    $('testSubject').slider({animate:"fast",min:0, max:20, step:1,value:0});
    });
```

I also maintained the relationship between the style sheet and the jquery ui images folder in my directory.

Thanks for helping me out with this silly question.

Comment: what means **stupid little issue**. you need to be patience. if the problem never come what we can learn from Programming. a good programmer never hate the problem they have perhaps like it to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Google hosts the themes as well, see:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

for example.

Comment: thanks rsp. I think I'll host my own theme so that I can tweak it manually. But this is good to know for future purposes

Answer (score 0):

yeah, for some reason it was a hosting fail.  I linked to Google's file, while also including the css file that I downloaded from the JqueryUI site.

It worked. Not sure what my issue was.